# get notes input control from timeline via javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm

I would like to be able to hook an `onChange` event for the default text input box for Notes in a Dynamics CRM timeline (activity feed). However, I am not allowed to manually pull it from the DOM incase breaking changes occur in the future so I was hoping I could find it as a control with fixed name, such as `fsdyn_notesinput` for example.

However I have been unable to retrieve the specific control I am after. I can find "Timeline" which I believe contains the text control I want but have failed to find a way to enumerate the timeline's children or anything like that.

The intention is for me to be able to live check what is being typed into the box to look for special terms such as tags and provide additional functionality. I am very new to Dynamics development so it may be I am approaching this all wrong!

Currently I have nothing to share other than the typescript timeline fetch, which works:

```
let test2 = executionContext.getFormContext().getControl("Timeline");
```

We are using the new unified interface in the cloud.

Comment: Did  you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I did not! But a year and half (almost) on if I was desperate to do something like this today I would probably write a custom PCF component that posted to a timeline on submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hook an event handler to Notes control events in a supported way.

Instead, you can keep a multiline textbox in the entity form & `onChange` can be triggered on that field - you can provide additional functionality from here. You can create a Note (annotation) record with the content in this multiline field on record save.

In case of Notes creation from activity feed anywhere outside the entity form like dashboard, you should try C# Plugin on Notes record creation.

Comment: this is what I expected, thanks for being so clear! I was hoping to be able to hook the onchange so I could make live suggestions/auto-complete for things like tagging. EG, on a contacts feed someone makes a note that the contact had some interaction with a particular project and @projectname in the boxand it would replace the @ with a link to that project entity AND make a copy of the activity post on the projects feed too. I can certainly do this with a plugin.. but I hope they don't typo their tags!